# "Failed to get document because the client is offline" error in Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Here is my code of App.xaml.cs file of a Xamarin.Forms project:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
        public App()
        {
            CrossFirebaseCrashlytics.Current.HandleUncaughtException();

            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new Page();

            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await Loader());
        }

        
        private async Task Loader()
        {
            var firebaseDocExists = false;

            var firebaseDoc = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
                                                       .Instance
                                                       .Collection("myCollection")
                                                       .Document("docId")
                                                       .GetAsync();

            firebaseDocExists = firebaseDoc.Exists;

            if (firebaseDocExists == false) MainPage = new MyPage();
            else MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }
}
```

At the launch of the Android app **on physical devices (API level 29 and 31), not on the emulator, I get the following error**:

*crc64[alphanumeric_string].CrashlyticsException: Plugin.CloudFirestore.CloudFirestoreException: Failed to get document because the client is offline.
at MyApp.App.Loader ()(:0)
at MyApp.App.<.ctor>b__0_0 ()(:0)*

Before the first Firestore reference in my initial code, I added this new line of code:

```
await CrossCloudFirestore.Current.Instance.EnableNetworkAsync();
```

No difference at all.

I also should add that running the app on the emulator does not produce the error, regardless which API level I use.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please search before posting.  There are numerous [existing questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=Failed+to+get+document+because+the+client+is+offline+site:stackoverflow.com) about this error message

Comment: I have already looked a couple of them. Didn't find anything that could give me a solution.