# System.ArgumentException: 'Type 'MyApp.DatabaseFields+TableFields' does not have a default constructor Parameter name: type'

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, linker

In a Xamarin.Android project I get the error of the title, when I have linking enabled and set to "Sdk and User Assemblies".

Particularly, I get the following 2 unhandled exceptions:

> *System.ArgumentException: 'Type 'MyApp.DatabaseFields+TableFields' does not have a default constructor
> Parameter name: type'*

Here is the line from my Xamarin.Forms project that causes the 1st one:

`if (myDocument.ToObject<DatabaseFields>().myString1 == "string1")`

And that's the file that models the database's fields. Here is my code:

```
internal class DatabaseFields
{
    public class TableFields
    {
        public string myString1 { get; set; }

        public string myString2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I hit the "Continue" button, I get the following error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'CreatorCache`1' threw an exception.'

What should I change to prevent the errors?

Comment: You can try to set the linking to "None" and then add the `<AndroidEnableProfiledAot>false</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>` in the **<PropertyGroup>** of the `CSPROJ` file.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT
I have already done that. Disabling AOT and setting the linking to `None` makes the app run smoothly, without issues. The thing is that I don't want to disable linking. I want to identify what causes the issues and exclude it. By using `Preserve(AllMembers = true)` I solved the initial problem, but it led to another error, that I describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77254241/system-nullreferenceexception-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obj
I have added many assemblies to `linkskip` trying to solve the new issue, without any success.

Comment: This issue persists in release mode, and I noticed that there's an open issue:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/8378, you can continue following up on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use `PreserveAttribute` to tell the linker not to remove. I recommend reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) so you understand why it's needed. You probably also want to read about the [XML linker configuration files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker) as well. Linking is typically only used in Release configuration.

Comment: I was getting errors in Release configuration. I enabled debugging for the Release configuration ("Enable developer instrumentation (debugging and profiling)"), but it didn't have any effect. I get this message in Visual Studio:  `Android application is running (debug is disabled in android project properties).`. As debugging didn't work for me in Release mode, I decided to enable linking for the Debugging configuration which gave the errors I described.

Comment: By the way I altered my code like this:

`internal class DatabaseFields
{
   [Android.Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class TableFields
    {
        public string myString1 { get; set; }

        public string myString2 { get; set; }
    }
}`

It removed the error, but for some reason I don't get some data from the Firestore database. Running the app in Release mode continues to give me the same errors.

Comment: Now is the "fun" part. You have to find all the stuff that the linker is stripping out that is actually needed. It's mostly stuff that is accessed via reflection. On Android, you will want to pay close attention to the adb output (or the Visual Studio "Device Log" tab) while running your program. You'll find you get a `MissingMethodException` pointing to the missing method/object that was linked out. Add that to your XML file, or if it's code you control, use the `PreserveAttribute`. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Well definitely there is no `MissingMethodException`. Here is the error I get: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77194626/failed-to-get-document-because-the-client-is-offline-error-in-xamarin-forms-pr and it goes away if I disable linking. Enabling it (either "**Sdk Assemblies Only**" or "**Sdk and User Assemblies**") has as a result the aforementioned error.