# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. from Firestore when linking is enabled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, linker, linker-errors

Here is my Xamarin.Forms code:

```
IDocumentSnapshot myVariable = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
                                                        .Instance
                                                        .Collection("myCollection")
                                                        .Document("myDocument")
                                                        .GetAsync();
```

And here is the value of `myVariable`, when I run the Android app **with linking enabled**:

```
myVariable  {Plugin.CloudFirestore.DocumentSnapshotWrapper}
            Data       System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            Exists     true
            Id         "myDocument"
            Reference  {Plugin.CloudFirestore.DocumentReferenceWrapper}
```

Although, I get `myVariable.Exists` is `true`, I get no `Data`. I get `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

**If I disable linking I get the Data without issues.**

Any solutions to the problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. Yet I can't pinpoint what I should exclude from the linker. I have already added `Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore.dll` to **linkskip** with no success.

Comment: You should remove all firebase packages not just FireStore

Comment: I have added many others:
`<AndroidLinkSkip>Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics.dll;Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore.dll;Google.Cloud.Firestore.dll;Xamarin.Firebase.Common.dll;Plugin.FirebaseCrashlytics.dll;Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.dll;Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.Interop.dll</AndroidLinkSkip>`
No luck so far. I don't see the point adding some, like Analytics for example.